# Error in array allocation in C

Tags: c, pointers

i've try to compile this simple program, it will alloc a dyamic array and return it with a multiple of 5 in every location. but it doesn't work, it report me an error in the pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int n;
    int i;
    int* ptra;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    ptra = malloc(n*(sizeof(int)));

    for(i=0; i<=n; i++){
        ptra[i] = (5*(i+1));
        printf("%d\n", ptra[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indent your code please.

Comment: An array of `n` integers contains elements in the range from `0` to `n - 1`. Now take a look at your loop again, and think about that loop condition.

Comment: it should be for(i=0;i<n;i++)

Comment: _, it report me an error in the pointer_ which error ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz how can i ident my code?

Comment: ok i've fix the loop condition but the program still doesn't work

Comment: @fenigo69 somebody has done it for you and edited the question. You see the difference ?

Comment: `i<=n` should be `i<n`. Voting to close this as simple typo.

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't work". If it doesn't build then please include the build errors. If it crashes then use a debugger to locate where in your code it happens. If you get unexpected output then include the input and the expected *and* actual output.

Comment: it compile it, but when i run it, it report me "the program it not reconized as a executive program or a batch file"

Comment: sorry guys, i've change compiler, now it working without problem, thanks everybodys

Comment: In that case I think you should delete the question, as it's not really useful in its current form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index range for `ptra` must be from `0` to `n-1` (both inclusive). But here:

```
for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
```

you are going out of bounds, which is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Change it to:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
```

Note: Always check the return of all the standard functions for failures (`scanf()` and `malloc()` in your code).

Comment: Did you add the error checking I suggested? Please describe what "doesn't work". It [works as expected](http://ideone.com/I5rfrg).

Comment: the compiler compile the program, but when i'm going to run it,report me "the program It is not recognized as executive program or a batch file"

Comment: That appears to a problem with your environment. Check your `PATH` is correct. See [this](http://superuser.com/questions/943785/sample-exe-not-recognised-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or) and related posts linked in that page.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is going one step beyond the limit: must go as long as **`i<n`** and not **`i<=n`**

try doing:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
```

Comment: it report me "the program It is not recognized as executive program or a batch file"